# Table structure for an attribute that allows checkbox and text

Tags: mysql

We often have scenarios where we have a group of checkboxes (or radio buttons) with "other" option that lets user enter whatever they want in textbox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H81O.png

I am struggling with coming up with MySQL structure for this.

Possible solutions:

1)Store user's selection as free text (irrespective of whether they selected a predefined option or used "other" option). I lose the benefit of avoiding data redundancy using foreign key. I also lose the benefit of data integrity but since I am allowing user to enter free text, I don't know how important that is.

2)Have two columns - checkbox option_id and option_text. I don't lose the benefit of foreign key and data redundancy but I have another column per group of checkboxes. (I have too many of such groups.)

3)Any alternatives?

Comment: Option 2 is how I would do it.

Comment: @Lock How about JSON?

Comment: I wouldn't be storing serialized data. You will loose the ability to filter, sort, index etc plus you will have to handle the serializing/deserializing on the client end.